# Jssor Slider Source Example

Tags: html, jssor

I will like to achieve the slider example in this [a link](http://www.jssor.com/demos/full-width-slider.html) using the same Jssor Slider, but the page doesn't have any sample or source code for it.

Any help with this we be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: http://www.jssor.com/development/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please [Download Jssor Slider](http://www.jssor.com/download.html) and open 'demos-jquery\full-width-slider.source.html'